# spawn process from php in windows that does not wait for command to complete

Tags: php, iis-7

How can i spawn a process from PHP 5.6.40 running on Windows IIS7 that returns immediately ?

I've tried the following but it waits for the command to complete :

```
exec("start ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul 2>&1");
```

It seems under windows, PHP always waits for any spawned process to complete. There are lots of answers for Linux that appear to work.

Comment: development question -> off topic. PHP 5 ... ouch ... so much more off topic ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250799/php-execute-command-and-log-output-without-waiting

Comment: oops sorry - i saw other php related questions in serverfault so thought it a good place for the question.